cross URLs between “location” and “listing-category” listing on wp
I am trying to make a site like yelp but I can not find a theme on wp to seo cross URLs between “location” and “listing-category” (the list of locations is set manually), all templates on temforrest do not have seo, please tell me what can be used?
I need to combine in url and to be able to have meta tags for each combination page
example: www.example.com/restaurants/new-york/
thanks
